# iPad 4.3 UIButtons not working when animation is animating

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have a button that moves up to the center of the screen. I also have images around the screen that are animating. When you click on the button in iPad 5.0, it works. However, it doesn't even respond to a click or a "Touch Down" event in 4.3. I noticed it only has this problem when there's something animating on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: On what thread are your animations taking place? It may be that they are blocking the main thread and preventing UI interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [*UIView Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW109):

> During an animation, user interactions are temporarily disabled for the views being animated. (Prior to iOS 5, user interactions are disabled for the entire application.) If you want users to be able to interact with the views, include the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` constant in the *options* parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Also, if anyone else makes the same assumption that I did (ie place the `UIViewAnimationAllowUserInteraction` on the animated button only), you'd also need to set that constant in every animation in the same View if you have multiple animations.

Comment: i was having same problem. i have uibutton inside custom view and it is animating.. but not clickable. this answer was helped~! thank you~